# Execute Pop, Discard and Remove commands on Sets

Tags: python

If someone can help to understand the following eval logic and how the particular method is applied in this scenario.

```
n = int(input())
s = set(map(int, input().split()))

for i in range(int(input())):
    eval('s.{0}({1})'.format(*input().split()+['']))

print(sum(s))
```

The above code works absolutely fine and I'm trying to understand how the function works in details.

[Here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/py-set-discard-remove-pop/problem) is the reference to the problem.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Andra, and this is also a very good alternative solution:

```
n = int(input())
s = set(map(int, input().split()))
d = {"pop":s.pop, "remove":s.remove, "discard": s.discard}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    c = input().split()
    d[c[0]](int(c[1])) if len(c)>1 else d[c[0]]()
print(sum(s))
```

Comment: Good use of a dict for mapping commands to functions. But this line `d[c[0]](int(c[1])) if len(c)>1 else d[c[0]]()` is pretty difficult to unwind. Try using some intermediate variables. This will take multiple lines, but cramming everyting into one-line is not always helpful.  Something like `fn = d.get(c[0]); if fn is not None: if len(c) > 1: fn(int(c[1])  else: fn()` (unf. I can't format multiple lines in a comment, but these should be separate lines).

Comment: Testing if fn is not None will guard against input of a word other than the expected pop/remove/discard.  Extra credit: How would you add support for adding an element to s?

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcG and I'll give it a shot, Do you think the first solution may work better that is in the top?

Comment: `eval()` is a common function for beginners to use, but it has serious security issues if used in a production application, so I recommend against it. The approach you are using is much more the way a more advanced user would do it. But you should really study each line of this and really understand what each one does.

Comment: ^ Please correct me if I'm wrong but it works as this:
    `if len(c)>1:
        d[c[0]](int(c[1])) 
    else:
        d[c[0]]()`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow. If you're a begineer in Python, I recommend you to read [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/), they provide a good resource to understand Python.

For this problem, you need to read https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Okay, let's break the code line by line.

```
n = int(input())
```

Take an input string from stdin, then convert it to `int` data type. Then store it to variable `n`

```
s = set(map(int, input().split()))
```

Take an input, and split it on every whitespace. e.g If the input is `1 2 3`, it will  be a list of `[1, 2, 3]`. Then, convert every element of the list to an int data type. Then, convert the list to set. Then store it to variable `s`.

```
for i in range(int(input())):
```

Iterate from 0 to a string from input and converted to int data type as `i`

```
    eval('s.{0}({1})'.format(*input().split()+['']))
```

Okay, this will go a bit tricky.

First, try to understand the Python format, I recommend you to read https://pyformat.info/. In short, `"string {0}, {2}, {1}".format("a", "b", "c")` will give you string of `"string a, c, b"`.

In this case, the format will take 2 argument, because there's `{0}` and `{1}` in the string `'s.{0}({1})'`, which comes from `*input().split()+['']` statement.

Python will execute `input().split()` first, take an input and split it to a list. Then merge the list with another list, which is `['']`. After that, spread the list elements as the argument of the format.

e.g
If you have the input

```
remove 9
```

It will call the format like this

```
's.{0}({1})'.format("remove", "9", "")
# will be
's.remove(9)'
```

```
"remove 9" -> ["remove", "9"] -> ["remove", "9", ""] -> "remove", "9", "" (as function argument)
```

Okay, but what's the `+['']` for? It's a trick for the formatter for input that only has one word.

e.g

```
's.{0}({1})'.format("pop", "")
# will be
's.pop()'
```

Eval function take one argument, which is string. And it will execute the string as a Python code. So, `eval("print(1)")` will print `1` to console.

```
print(sum(s))
```

Print the sum of set `s`

I hope I explain it clear enough